# Entire date list is repeated for each month EMI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make a Amortization Schedule table. I am getting the data but the dates are not being displayed properly. For each monthly interest, principal and balance all the dates(the entire month list) are repeated. This is what I am getting

```
Date    Interest    Principal   Balance
6/04/2021 29        820          9180
6/05/2021 29        820          9180
6/06/2021 29        820          9180
....
6/04/2021 27        822          8358
6/05/2021 27        822          8358
6/06/2021 27        822          8358
```

For the next EMI the entire month list gets repeated
The Result should be like this

```
Date    Interest    Principal   Balance
6/04/2021 29        820          9180
6/05/2021 27        822          8358
```

...
Thank you for your help.
This is the model class

```
public class AmortizationSchedule
{
         [DisplayName("Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate{get;set;}
        public List<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Interest { get; set; }
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
        public decimal Principal { get; set; }
}
```

This is the View

```
@model IEnumerable<AmortizationCalculator.Web.Models.AmortizationSchedule>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th>Principal</th>
            <th>Balance</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            @foreach (var q in item.Date)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <li>@q.ToShortDateString()</li>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Interest
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Principal
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Balance
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>

</table>
```

These are the methods from which I get the EMI , and the list of months between the start and the end date

```
    public class AmortizedLib
    {

        public List<AmortizationSchedule> AmortizationScheduleCalculation(decimal totalAmount
        , decimal rate, decimal downPayment
            ,int loanTerm, DateTime startDate)
        {
            decimal EMI;
            decimal principal = totalAmount - downPayment;
            decimal monthlyInterest;
            decimal monthlyPrincipal;
            decimal newPrincipalBalance;
            int numberOfEMI = loanTerm * 12;
            int year = loanTerm * 12;

            DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endDate = Date.AddMonths(year);

            Console.WriteLine(endDate);

            EMI = Math.Round(monthlyPayments(principal, rate, loanTerm));

            List<AmortizationSchedule> schedules = new List<AmortizationSchedule>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfEMI; i++)
            {
                monthlyInterest = Math.Round((principal * rate / 100) / 12);
                monthlyPrincipal = Math.Round(EMI - monthlyInterest);
                newPrincipalBalance = Math.Round(principal - monthlyPrincipal);
                principal = newPrincipalBalance;

                AmortizationSchedule amortizationSchedule = new AmortizationSchedule();

                    amortizationSchedule.Interest = monthlyInterest;
                    amortizationSchedule.Principal = monthlyPrincipal;
                    amortizationSchedule.Balance = newPrincipalBalance;
                    amortizationSchedule.Date = EachMonth(startDate, endDate, year).ToList();

                schedules.Add(amortizationSchedule);
            }

            return schedules;
        }

        // to calculate monthly EMI
        public static decimal monthlyPayments(decimal actualPrincipal, decimal rate, double loanTerm)
        {
            rate = rate / 1200;
            loanTerm = loanTerm * 12;
            decimal F = (decimal)Math.Pow((double)(1 + rate), loanTerm);
            return actualPrincipal * ((rate * F) / (F - 1));
        }

// to get the time list of  months
        public static IEnumerable<DateTime> EachMonth(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate , int term)
        {
            int months = term;
            startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            endDate = startDate.AddMonths(months);


            for (var day = startDate.Date; day.Date <= endDate.Date; day = day.AddMonths(1))
                yield return day;
        }


    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bEo3.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in the Model as well the calculationMethod.
The model should not have had the List just plain date property and the foreach loop should include the entire method

```
public class AmortizationSchedule{
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Interest { get; set; }
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
        public decimal Principal { get; set; }
}
```

The method should be

```
        public List<AmortizationSchedule> AmortizationScheduleCalculation(decimal totalAmount
        , decimal rate, decimal downPayment
            ,int loanTerm, DateTime startDate)
        {
            decimal EMI;
            decimal principal = totalAmount - downPayment;
            decimal monthlyInterest;
            decimal monthlyPrincipal;
            decimal newPrincipalBalance;
            int numberOfEMI = loanTerm * 12;
            int year = loanTerm * 12;

            DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endDate = Date.AddMonths(year);

            Console.WriteLine(endDate);

            EMI = Math.Round(monthlyPayments(principal, rate, loanTerm));
            List<AmortizationSchedule> schedules = new List<AmortizationSchedule>();
            int i = 0;
            var monthlyDateList = EachMonth(startDate, endDate, year).ToList();
            foreach (var item in monthlyDateList)
            {
                monthlyInterest = Math.Round((principal * rate / 100) / 12);
                monthlyPrincipal = Math.Round(EMI - monthlyInterest);
                newPrincipalBalance = Math.Round(principal - monthlyPrincipal);
                principal = newPrincipalBalance;

                AmortizationSchedule amortizationSchedule = new AmortizationSchedule();
                amortizationSchedule.Date = item;
                amortizationSchedule.Interest = monthlyInterest;
                amortizationSchedule.Principal = monthlyPrincipal;
                amortizationSchedule.Balance = newPrincipalBalance;
                schedules.Add(amortizationSchedule);
                i++;
            }

            return schedules;

        }
```

The view should be

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th>Principal</th>
            <th>Balance</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Date.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Interest
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Principal
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Balance
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```